# Open service port out of Docker

Tags: iptables, docker, port, nmap

In installed some docker application on my virtual server, and I never modified the iptables policies.
When I run a full nmap to the virtual server I obtain,

```
Host is up (0.044s latency).
Not shown: 65521 closed ports
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp   open     ssh
80/tcp   open     http
135/tcp  filtered msrpc
139/tcp  filtered netbios-ssn
443/tcp  open     https
445/tcp  filtered microsoft-ds
593/tcp  filtered http-rpc-epmap
2022/tcp open     down
4444/tcp filtered krb524
5554/tcp filtered sgi-esphttp
8000/tcp open     http-alt
8005/tcp open     mxi
8006/tcp open     wpl-analytics
9996/tcp filtered palace-5
```

Running `iptables -L` on the virtual server I obtain,

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8496
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8495
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8490
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8386
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8486
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8485
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8480
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8476
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8475
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8470
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8466
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8465
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8460
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8456
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8455
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8445
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8430
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8426
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8450
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8446
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8440
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8436
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8435
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8425
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8420
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8416
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8415
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8410
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8406
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8405
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8400
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8396
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8395
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8390
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8385
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8380
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8376
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8375
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8370
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8366
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8365
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8360
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8356
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8355
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8350
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8346
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8345
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8340
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8336
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8335
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8330
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8326
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8325
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8320
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8316
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8315
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8310
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8306
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8305
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8300
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8296
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8295
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8276
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8290
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8286
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8285
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8280
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8275
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8270
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8266
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8265
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8260
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8256
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8255
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8250
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8246
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8245
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8240
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8236
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8235
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8230
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8226
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8225
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8220
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8216
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8215
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8205
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8210
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8206
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8200
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8196
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8195
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8190
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8186
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8185
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8180
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8176
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8175
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8170
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8166
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8165
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8160
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8156
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8155
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8145
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8150
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8146
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:puppet
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8116
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8136
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8135
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8130
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8126
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8125
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8120
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8115
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8110
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8106
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8105
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8100
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8096
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8095
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8090
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8065
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8076
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8075
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8070
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8066
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8060
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8056
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8055
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8050
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8046
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8045
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8040
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8036
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8035
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8030
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8026
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8025
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8020
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8016
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8015
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8010
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8006
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8005
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.6           tcp dpt:2022
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.6           tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.6           tcp dpt:http

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Now I installed a service using port 60000 as both, source and destination, but if I open ports with,

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 60000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 60000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 60000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 60000 -j ACCEPT
```

Ports don't result opened.

```
Host is up (0.039s latency).

PORT      STATE  SERVICE
60000/tcp closed unknown
```

How could I solve?
Thank you.

Ivan

Comment: Is that application listening on that port inside the container, on all interfaces (not just loopback/127.0.0.1)? Include how you are running the container and publishing the port.

Comment: Solved! Restart was needed...